# How to check if a mining pool runs the forking client or not? [The DAO]

Tags: the-dao, mining-pools, gas-limit, forks

As Geth and Parity forking version are out, [the switch to a soft fork related to The DAO is said to happend on block 1800000 if block gas limit is below or equal to 4M.](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/24/dao-wars-youre-voice-soft-fork-dilemma/) We can see global gas limit on sites like https://ethstats.net/ but they don't represent the whole Ethereum system.

But how to check a particular pool (Ethermine on which I mine is [0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8](https://live.ether.camp/account/EA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8)) gas limit to see if it runs the client in this particular fork mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The block `gasLimit` is in each block.  Example:

> eth.getBlock(1500000)

```
{
  difficulty: 34982465665323,
  extraData: "0xd783010305844765746887676f312e352e31856c696e7578",
  gasLimit: 4712388,
  miner: ...
  ...
}
```

If the `gasLimit` of the next block decreases, it suggests that the client is running the fork mode to try to bring the `gasLimit` below 4M.

The `extraData` and `miner` in the block can provide clues on which mining pool it is.  (Note that miners don't have to set `extraData` and can change their `miner` address.)

Comment: So I could look at the gas limit in http://etherscan.io/blocks?m=0xEA674fdDe714fd979de3EdF0F56AA9716B898ec8 and if it decreases it means that the pool runs for the fork ?

Comment: Ethermine and DwarfPool both show a 4,712,388 Wei gas limit, same since at least a week, so I guess the fork didn't start for these pools.

Comment: Yes, keep an eye out on the blocks they mine to see if `gasLimit` decreases.

Comment: Etherscan put a nice graph to check the gas limit and Ethermine gas limit started to decrease so the fork vote is starting.